# Refresh current view when application in foreground and push notification received?

Tags: ios, push-notification

I am making one game.It's a real time turned based game. 
User make his turn will wait in game borad screen and his opponent put his turn then user will receive one push notification.

Now my problem is that app is foreground and we have view controller and now how we will refresh the game board when push notification received.

My problem is that I am getting call back in appdelegate but how refresh the the game board view controller which is coming after 2 steps pushing from window of root viewcontroller. My root view controller is navigation controller.

Navigations :
Window --> NavigationController --> OnelistViewController--> GameBoardViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options there. The first one would be to arrange that your app delegate gets a direct reference to your GameBoardViewController instance. This is a typical problem you can solve with [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). So instead of creating your GameBoardController from your OnelistViewController you create it in your app delegate (or ideally even in some class that does nothing but instantiate other objects) and give that instance to your OnelistViewController.

The other alternative would be to send a notification using `NSNotificationCenter` and listen for that notification in your GameBoardViewController. This would be the preferred way to distribute those push notifications if there are multiple objects that are interested in push notifications and the application delegate doesn’t need to know about them otherwise.

Comment: Great! I already implemented NSNotiifcationCenter but have not tested it yet..will test shorlty..Thanks